# .scrollTop position of scrollable element cached by UIWebView with overflow scrolling

Tags: javascript, ios, css, uiwebview, hybrid-mobile-app

I am currently developing a hybrid mobile app which makes use of `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` on the "content area" to provide smooth scrolling.

I have hit somewhat of a road block however when using this feature. Upon scroll (I check with an `.onAnimationFrame` loop) I check the .scrollTop position to see if any movement has occured so that I can let various components within the application know of this so they can perform certain actions (Use case examples may be parallax scrolling, controlling culled rendering etc.). This is all well and good when testing in a desktop browser (Ie. Chrome 41) however when debugging within iOS Safari OR iOS UIWebView the scrollTop position seems to be cached when there is a large amount of movement (Eg. a user flicking the view)

This caching means that other elements expecting to know the exact current scrollTop value will fall behind and the view becomes out of sync.

My presumption is that overflow scrolling forces rendering onto the gpu so I'm wondering if there is *any* way to get around this or to force invalidation of the cached scrollTop value.

**DEMONSTRATION**: http://jsfiddle.net/skpmkjea/ (load up in safari on an ios device and connect to debugger to see console log of scroll top positions)

Things I've tried:

- Forcing an empty element in and out of the root body to try and force a full page update to re-calculate the scrollTop value
- Using a container div within the scroll element and checking for the bounding box updating `.getBoundingClientRect()` but this seems to have the same cached values

More info (I'll add more if it would help anyone):

- UIWebView build with Cordova
- My main test target is iOS7
- The issue exists but is much less noticeable (ie. cached value invalidation appears to occur at intervals) on android 4